# Error for the query statement with CASE and Count

Tags: sql, oracle, case

This is my original query statement....

```
 SELECT airline company, country, count(country) "The no.of times the airline visits the country"
 FROM [table]
 GROUP BY airline company, country
```

I think this works fine...until I want to add a case statement where there is an error......

After modification,

```
 Airline Company      : country  : No.Of times
   Singapore Airline  : SG       :   5
   Singapore Airline  : MAL      :   7
   Japan Airline      : SG       :   3
   Japan Airline      : MAL      :   2
```

After the 1st query statement, the result is shown as above. I would like to change the value of No.of times column to 0 regardless of the airline for the country 'MAL'. So I tried to add the case statement to the select, but it gives me like group function is not allowed

```
 SELECT airline company, country, CASE WHEN country = 'MAL' THEN 0 
                                       ELSE count(country) "The no.of times the airline visits the country" END
 FROM [table]
 GROUP BY airline company, country, CASE WHEN country = 'MAL' THEN 0 
                                       ELSE count(country) "The no.of times the airline visits the country" END
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Your current query should already be generating the output you want.  What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do `Conditional Aggregation` :

```
SELECT airline_company, country, 
       COUNT ( CASE WHEN country = 'MAL' THEN NULL 
                    ELSE country 
                    END ) as "# of times the airline visits"
  FROM [table]
 GROUP BY airline_company, country
```

Comment: It works like magic....But I wonder why the above of mine wouldn't work....

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the "CASE" condition inside the "group by" to achieve what you want, just keep it in the select stmt.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple issues in your query:

- If `airline company` is the column name then it must be wrapped in the double quotes in a case sensitive manner: `"airline company"` or `"AIRLINE COMPANY"`. because oracle does not allow direct use of the columns containing the spaces
- You are trying to give alias `"The no.of times the airline visits the country"` before your case expression is ended. You must give an alias to case expression after `END`
- There is no need of the `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause as case expression only uses one column directly(`COUNTRY`) which is already present in `GROUP BY` clause.

So your query must look like following:

> ```
> SELECT
>     "AIRLINE COMPANY", -- added double quotes
>     COUNTRY,
>     CASE
>         WHEN COUNTRY = 'MAL' THEN 0
>         ELSE COUNT(COUNTRY)
>     END AS "The no.of times the airline visits the country" 
>     -- alias is given after END keyword
> FROM
>     YOUR_TABLE
> GROUP BY
>     "AIRLINE COMPANY",
>     COUNTRY
>     -- ,CASE -- commented this
>     --    WHEN COUNTRY = 'MAL' THEN 0
>     --    ELSE COUNT(COUNTRY)
>     -- END AS "The no.of times the airline visits the country"
> ```

Cheers!!